# Online Postgraduate (Statistics / Mathematics)

Tags: graduate-school, masters

I decided to begin an european online Postgraduate (MA, MSc or none) related with Statistics or Mathematics. The restriction of european ones, is because I'm spanish, and the tuition fees are way cheaper that way.

The problem I found is that the Universities that offer these kind of postgraduates are pretty unkown, to the point that I feel a bit doubtful about what I could learn there.

I tried to find some Postgraduates through internet Master searchers, but I found almost no information about online Postgraduates, either because the searchers ignore most european Universities, or because they don't distinguish between online and presencial studies.

My question, therefore, is, what would be the best way to find a Postgraduate of such characteristics.

Comment: The current format of this question is unclear. Please clarify what you mean by "interesting". Once you clarify it, your question could become of "shopping" nature or too broad.

Comment: What country are you actually living in? There are differences between doing an online postgraduate course in your own country and in another country. For example, Open University in United Kingdom is excellent, but you must be a UK resident to even apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open University offers a Masters in Mathematics, available to anyone (even outside UK). See http://www.open.ac.uk/postgraduate/qualifications/f04.

A simple Google search on "masters" "mathematics" and "online" or "distance" gives enough results which you can then cross join with university rankings.

Is there a particular area you would like study? If online only, why restrict yourself to EU? (e.g. there is applied math at UW, Seattle etc).

Comment: The restriction to EU is because of the fees. Being european, EU universities are way cheaper than any other University would be.

Comment: I see. What resources do you have available then? Open University will charge ca. 8500 GBP for online masters in mathematics.